# django: automatically detect CRUD changes done on database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-database

I'm building an application(log) which stores the CRUD operations done on database.Is there any way to detect the CRUD operations directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [django's model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals).

Alternatively, you could use one of the many existing packages that provide this functionality. Find a comparison here: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/